# How to copy data from multiple table from one DB to other DB in sql server 2014 where Timestamp is used for all the tables

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I need to copy a set of tables from one DB to another DB, the tables structure is the same but the problem is when using Import/Export wizard I'm getting error that for table.

Timestamp is used as column for all the set of tables which we cannot use for copy, so some one please suggest how to copy the data from db to db.

**Error:**

- Validating (Error)
  Messages
  Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "timestamp".
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - Currency" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: As the error says, you can't insert into the `timestamp` Column. `timestamp` is a **deprecated** synonym of `rowversion` and inserting a value into it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

If DBs are on the same server you can use

INSERT INTO DESTDB.DBO.TB1
SELECT * FROM SOURCEDB.DBO.TB2

Comment: If DBs are not on the same server you can use linked server.

Comment: EVen if the tables *are* the same, this might not work. The OP's scenario, where they have a `rowversion` column is one example. Another is if it has an `IDENTITY` column. Another would be if the table had any computed columns.

Comment: Ok, maybe I haven't understood your question, but with identity column you can enable IDENTITY_INSERT. I don't know with row version.

Comment: See my comment under the question in regards to `rowversion`.